# WPF App - Async await method call is not rendering progress message

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am building a simple WPF application and would like to show the progress in the label field. But i am getting the progress message only for the first time but not on subsequent executions.

On subsequent button clicks, i am only seeing the message "Query executed successfully".

I am not sure where i am getting wrong.. I am trying to print the progress message. Please suggest, where am i making the mistake and which code statements needs to be moved or refactored.

```
  private async void btnRunQuery_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtQueries.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            lblMsg.Content = "Query execution in progress....  Please wait ....";
            lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        }

        await PopulateQueryExecutionResult();
    }       

private async Task PopulateQueryExecutionResult()
    {
        ResultList.ItemsSource = null; //Clear the control hierarchy before binding.

        if (txtQueries.Text.Length > 0)
        {                
            lblMsg.Content = "Query execution in progress....  Please wait ....";
            lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

            btnExport.IsEnabled = true;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConstructConnectionString(cmbEnv.SelectedValue.ToString(), cmbDbs.SelectedValue.ToString()));

            string commandtext = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;";  //Make Dirty read to prevent locking
            commandtext += txtQueries.Text;

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(commandtext, sqlconn);
                await sqlconn.OpenAsync();

                dp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                dp.Fill(ds, "QueryData");
                dt = ds.Tables["QueryData"];

                ResultList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                sqlconn.Close();

                lblMsg.Content = "Query executed successfully";
                lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception in the Query ::--> {0} \n\n StackTrace ::--> {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("At least write some query first!!!", "Query Execution Tool");
        }           

    }
```

Comment: You need to use Progress class. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Comment: Also, you should not be manipulating ui controls from a non-gui thread. For a WPF application, I also recommend using MVVM. Then you can simply set a string Property in the ViewModel and have your Label bound to that.

Comment: @Fildor Where exactly is OP "manipulating ui controls from a non-gui thread"?

Comment: @Clemens Isn't he in `PopulateQueryExecutionResult()` ? By setting `lblMsg.Content = ... ` ?

Comment: PopulateQueryExecutionResult runs on the UI thread. The await keyword just states that the method makes async calls, i.e. `sqlconn.OpenAsync();`

Comment: @Clemens Dough, you are right ... I was seeing code that isn't there ... Sorry!!

Comment: Besides that, they don't "need to use Progress class". The code should just work.

Comment: @Karan use your debugger.

Comment: @Clemens ok, I shouldn't have written "need" - I'd still recommend doing it.

Comment: Is it possible that the code executes so fast, that you do not really see the other messages?

Comment: You could test that by setting a Delay of, say 5 seconds right before you set the final message.

Comment: By calling `await Task.Delay(5000);`

Comment: @Clemens, you are right. After placing the statement for delay, i can see the progress message..

Comment: @Clemens, please suggest how do i handle this thing or leave it as it is..

Comment: @Karan It was your idea to somehow visualize the progress of opening a DB connection. Now you should ask yourself whether that was actually necessary.

Comment: I second what Clemens sais. For production code, I'd not suggest using delays. I just suggested putting them in to verify that the messages in fact are displayed if they have the time. If I were you, I'd leave it at that (without the delays, of course). 1. You have the feedback that everything went fine, which is of course good to know. And 2. in case the db query should ever take longer time, you'll be notified that it is running. So, I don't see a problem with that. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On subsequent button clicks, i am only seeing the message "Query executed successfully".

That's probably because `OpenAsync()` method returns to fast for you to be able to actually see the "Query execution in progress..." message. This shouldn't be an issue. If you want your code to run slower, you could introduce a delay as suggested in the comments:

```
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(commandtext, sqlconn);
    await sqlconn.OpenAsync();
    await Task.Delay(3000); //<--

    dp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dp.Fill(ds, "QueryData");
    dt = ds.Tables["QueryData"];

    ResultList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    sqlconn.Close();

    lblMsg.Content = "Query executed successfully";
    lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception in the Query ::--> {0} \n\n StackTrace ::--> {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
}
```

But you probably don't want to. Leave your code as it is would be suggestion.

You may want to consider to excecute the `Fill` method on a background thread:

```
try
{
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(commandtext, sqlconn);
    await sqlconn.OpenAsync();

    dp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dp.Fill(ds, "QueryData");
        dt = ds.Tables["QueryData"];
    });

    ResultList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    sqlconn.Close();

    lblMsg.Content = "Query executed successfully";
    lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception in the Query ::--> {0} \n\n StackTrace ::--> {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
}
```

Comment: Well I suggested the delay just to verify that the messages actually are displayed. For production code, I'd never suggest such a thing!

Comment: Can you please suggest to use await with the Fill method.. Thats where UI main thread is getting blocked...

Comment: This is near the same answer as mine answered an hour earlier yet I get down voted without explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is that the DataAdapter's `Fill()` method is blocking, perhaps meaning consecutive attempts never complete but "Query executed successfully" is displayed wrongly. This could give you a false positive indicator that it must have completed first time.

What I recommend doing is changing the state of UI after the `Fill()` method has executed rather than after when it was called, and as it is a blocking method I would do something like this:

```
try
{
    await sqlconn.OpenAsync();

    using (SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(commandtext, sqlconn))
    {
        dp.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
        await Task.Run(() => (Action)delegate {
            dp.Fill(dt);
            ResultList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            lblMsg.Content = "Query executed successfully";
            lblMsg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            sqlconn.Close();
        });
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Exception in the Query ::--> {0} \n\n StackTrace ::--> {1} ", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
}
```

You may find that "Query executed successfully" does not appear any more, if that is the case then I'd suggest you have an error in your SQL rather than the code.

Koda